# Getting error as Session ID is null, using WebDriver after calling quit()?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I'm trying to run scripts in PAF . While executing PAF Getting error as Session ID is null, using WebDriver after calling quit()? any idea please answer.

Answer (score 0):

When we get session ID is null, The Steps to follow :-Build path→ Configure Build path→ add external jar files to our respective project.